# Base Class Pointer only getting a Derived class variable value and not the base class variable value why?

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

Here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Shape
{
    char obj;

public:
    int j;
    Shape();
    void displayModel();
};

class Line : public Shape
{
    char obj;

public:
    Line();
    void displayModel();
};

Shape::Shape()
{
    obj = 'S';
    j = 1;
}

void ::Shape::displayModel()
{
    cout << obj;
    cout << " Shape j:" << j << endl;
}

Line::Line()
{
    obj = 'L';
    j = 5;
}

void Line::displayModel()
{
    cout << obj;
    cout << " Line j:" << j << endl;
}

int main()
{
    Shape *objPtr = NULL, s;
    Line l;
    objPtr = &l;

    s.displayModel();
    l.displayModel();
    objPtr->displayModel();

    return 0;
}
```

My doubt is when `objPtr->displayModel()` is executed why does `j=5` and not `j=1`? I know that `objPtr` is assigned to the address of object `l`. But I have not declared `virtual` keyword in `Shape::displayModel()`, so doesn't that mean that the compiler should check at the `type` of the object rather than what it points to? Or does that happen only for function calls when `virtual` keyword is declared and does not include variables?

So basically my doubt is why is `objPtr->displayModel()` printing `j=5` instead of `j=1`?

Comment: Your base class isn't virtual. `objPtr->displayModel()` calls `Shape::displayModel()` which prints `Shape::j`.

Comment: @Jonathan Potter But then isn't Shape::j value initialized to 1.So why j=5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why should `j` be different? There's only one `j`, which is declared in `Shape`. When you're deriving from `Shape`, you're not adding more `j`s, there would need to be some `j` declared in `Line`, too. On the other hand, you have separate `obj` for `Shape` and for `Line`, so that's why your program prints

```
S Shape j:1
L Line j:5
S Shape j:5
```

Note: If you make `void Shape::displayModel()` `virtual`, the call `objPtr->displayModel();` will propagate to `void Line::displayModel()` instead, and you'll get two `L`s:

```
S Shape j:1
L Line j:5
L Line j:5
```

Comment: So does that mean objPtr->j takes the value of object l's l.j ?So,basically what ever object objPtr will point to it will get that objects j value right?

Comment: Yes, but keep in mind, that it's actually `j` of `Shape` of `l`.

Comment: Yeah I know that. I was just having doubt before regarding what value objPtr->j will get,Shape's object's s.j value or the Line object's l.j value. Now it is clear.Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

`LogicStuff` is right.

Add markers, like `cout << 'In Shape::displayModel() function'` and `cout << 'In Line::displayModel() function'`

It should help you understand what append.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried the code but at first glance I can tell you two things:

The first is that to use polymorphism in c++ you need to use the "virtual" keyword. Classes with virtual functions or virtual methods are termed polymorphic.

```
class Shape{
private:
   char obj;  
public:
    int j;
    Shape();
    virtual void displayModel();
};
```

Second is that you should declare your object with the base static type and then use the derived dynamic type to instantiate it.

```
Shape *objPtr = new Line();
```

By using  virtual functions the program "remembers" the dynamic type and can thus invoke specific methods even after the objects are upcasted to a more general type.

Keep in mind that the way the compiler does this is giving the classes a virtual table to the classes that have virtual functions and thus consume more memory.

Hope this helps